# NullPointerException when trying to access TextView in CustomSpinner

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I am trying to use a custom spinner for my calender view. I have written my own custom adapter. The view loads fine initially but as soon as I try to click on one of the items in the spinner dropdown the app crashes.

Following is my Activity code :

```
public class CalendarEventsActivity  extends Activity {

protected ActivityHeader mHeader;
private Spinner mMonthDropdown;

@Override
protected void beforeMainContentCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

public void onCreateMainContent(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateMainContent(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientationByResourceID(R.integer.allow_landscape_calendar_events_activity);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_events);

    mHeader = (ActivityHeader) findViewById(R.id.header);

    getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);

    setupMonthSpinner();
}

private void setupMonthSpinner() {
    mMonthDropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.month_spinner);
    String[] items = new String[] { "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    mMonthDropdown.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.calendar_month_item, items));

    mMonthDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("you have now clicked......."+((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    String[] calendar_months;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.calendar_months = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_month_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);
        label.setText(calendar_months[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
}
```

This is xml where I am defining my layout for the Activity (activity_calendar_events.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.android.ui.ActivityHeader
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:actionButtonDrawable="@drawable/icon_add_member_inset"
    app:actionButtonDrawableHeight="35dp"
    app:actionButtonDrawableWidth="35dp"
    app:headerLabel="@string/calendar_events_header"
    app:menuButtonDrawable="@drawable/icon_navbar_back_inset"
    app:menuButtonDrawableHeight="35dp"
    app:menuButtonDrawableWidth="35dp"
    app:showMenuButton="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F4F4F4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/month_spinner"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#F4F4F4"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:popupBackground="#F4F4F4"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="2016" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the xml where I am defining the layout for the individual rows of the dropdown (calendar_month_item.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.calendar"
android:id="@+id/calendar_month"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:textColor="#181512"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textStyle="normal" />
```

And finally the Logcat error :

```
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at com.android.calendar.CalendarEventsActivity$1.onItemSelected(CalendarEventsActivity.java:78)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
04-19 14:27:06.073: E/ThisLife(13008):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I believe this is a pretty standard way for writing custom spinners. I tried debugging with breakpoints and all the data points at the specific line causing the NPE seem to be not null. I am not really sure whats going on here. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the entire `calendar_month_item.xml` file content? You are referencing one of its `TextView` in your code:                            `   `View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_month_item, parent, false);
TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);`

Comment: There was a problem with the formatting. Can you see it now. The whole file is there. Just contains one text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
System.out.println("you have now clicked......."+((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText().toString());
```

To

```
String selectedMonth    = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month)).getText().toString();
System.out.println("you have now clicked......."+selectedMonth);
```

Remember that according to your adapter, the getCustomView function returns an "inflated" `R.layout.calendar_month_item` whenever a view is requested. You then look-up the `R.id.calendar_month` on this view - which should contain the value of the selected month. Please check and confirm if this works. I hope it does.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and did work :) Thanks. I should have looked at the View element earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting adapter, instead of passing `this`, try `CalendarEventsActivity.this`. So it'll look like: 
`mMonthDropdown.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(CalendarEventsActivity.this, R.layout.calendar_month_item, items));`

Comment: Tried that. Still crashes.

Answer (score -1):

The id of the TextView is calendar_year while in your code, you have referenced calendar_month

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="2016" />

TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);
```

Comment: Sorry. I think I added it wrong. Its calendar_month in both places and still crashing.

Comment: Also that textview (calendar_year) is different and independent from the Spinner textview (calendar_month).